# What is the best way to handle Time objects in mySQL+prisma?

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma

I am using mySQL as a database and Prisma as an ORM and basically need to store Time objects without the Date part, e.g.
'1:12.55', '12.53', '0.59'

I tried to model my table in **schema.prisma** file like this:

```
model Result {
    attempt1 DateTime
}
```

Which resulted in the migration:

```
CREATE TABLE `Result` (
    `date` DATETIME() NOT NULL
}
```

How do I modify my schema.prisma content so that it creates a migration with **time** field type instead of **date**?

Comment: Which part of the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/mysql/introduction-to-data-types#dates-and-time/) do you not understand?  Can you show a [mre] of this problem ?

Comment: the docs are clear to me, I figured out that the time type would fit my requirements. But I cannot find a way to generate such a field using the Prisma's schema-first approach

Comment: What will you store when time is bigger than 24 hours?   I think you need a datetime to store that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store a time bigger than 24 hours, you will need to use a DateTime. If you want another way to store time, you could use an Integer and then store a Unix Timestamp. This is one of the way I use if needed.

If you are looking for something else, I do not understand what it is. Maybe you could look in the documentation for something similar?

Comment: I don't need to store times bigger than 24 hours, so I ended up using the integer type for that and store the timestamp in ms.

Answer (score -1):

To store only the date portion you could use the native @db.date attribute. That would just store the date and not store the time.

In your schema file you could update the model as below to just store the date portion:

```
model modelName {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt  DateTime @default(now()) @db.Date
  lastNumber Int
}
```

Here's a reference to Prisma's MySQL DateTime attribute: [Reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mysql#native-type-mappings)